# Get array of IDs from firestore to get documents from another collection with same IDs and combine their results into an Observable<Model[]>?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

**What I'm trying to do**

I have a list of customers, each customer have a list of invoice IDs, I store invoice IDs as separate documents (containing only a timestamp for order while document ID is same as invoiceID). What I want to do is, get these invoice IDs as an array, then get actual invoice from invoices collection, by ID, combine their results into a single Observable. So far I can only manage to get Observable[]>

**What I tried**

```
this.invoice$ = this.fs.collection('data').doc('admin').collection('customers').doc(this.customer.id)
.collection('invoiceIDs').snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(idSnapshots => idSnapshots.map(id => this.fs.collection('data').doc('admin')
  .collection('invoices').doc(id.payload.doc.id).valueChanges().pipe(map(invoice => new InvoiceModel({
    id: id.payload.doc.id,
    ...invoice
  })
)))));
```

This like I said results in an Observable of Observable array or Observable[]>.

**Result I want**

Result I want is, get the array of IDs, as snapshotChanges, map them to get ID, get documents from 'invoices' collection that belongs to these IDs, so that I can use *ngFor="let invoice of (invoice$ | async)" to display each invoice as a card.

**My current sloppy solution**

Right now, I can achieve a similar result by subscribing to IDs and assigning subscribed IDs to a different component, which is a messy solution, as seen here:

```
this.subs.push(this.fs.collection('data').doc('admin').collection('customers').doc(this.customer.id)
.collection('invoiceIDs').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(ids => ids.map(id => id.payload.doc.id))).subscribe(ids => {
  this.invoiceIDs = ids;
  this.cdref.detectChanges();
}));
```

Then I use *ngFor to get each invoice ID

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let invoice of invoiceIDs">
```

Assign each ID to a component I call

```
<m-finance-frame [id]="invoice">
```

Which gives the results I want but like I said, feels like a messy solution. Trying to solve this by making one Observable, that I can use with (Observable | async) over HTML rather than subscribing.

Comment: Can you please tell me if you are able to figure out the solution? I have a similar issue I am facing right now.

Comment: I solved this problem by storing customerId in Invoice instead of storing InvoiceIDs in customer, then queried Invoices by customerId, so not really a solution to question itself, just changed the way my code works.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!